# Export JaCoCo configuration to binary gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, plugins, jacoco

How does one export JaCoCo configuration to a plugin which can be re-used in multiple projects?

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class MyJacoco implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.configure(project) {
            apply plugin: 'jacoco'

            jacoco {
                toolVersion = "0.8.0"
            }
            jacocoTestReport { // throws up on this
                afterEvaluate {...}
                group = "Reporting"
                reports {...}
            }
        }

        println(project.getPlugins().findPlugin('jacoco'))

    }
}
```

In my projects I just want to use, when I publish...

```
apply plugin: MyJacoco
```

I've also tried [How to configure Gradle Java plugin from a custom Gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860095/how-to-configure-gradle-java-plugin-from-a-custom-gradle-plugin) but no results.

Comment: What's the reported error?